# API Platform slow on collections

Tags: php, docker, api, symfony, api-platform.com

I'm creating a web API with API Platform framework and I'm getting some performance issues with collections retrieving.

**Problem**

I would like to get a collection of a table (with relations) but it takes 20 secondes to load.

**Additional informations**

- Pagination enabled (by default 30 items / page).
- I use Symfony server:start for working.
- I work in WSL2 (in /home folder)
- I use MariaDB in docker
- APCu Enabled
- API Platform is not inside docker

Firstly I was expecting an I/O issue because I was working in /mnt. I moved the project into /home and in fact performances were better except for when I tried to get the collection.

Then, I tried to get other collections and some of them worked fast.
I also tried to queryparam with itemPage = 1 but it takes between 15 and 20 secondes...

I'm supposing the problem can be encountered against the code but I'm not sure...

Here are some logs :

*The entity*

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use ApiPlatform\Core\Annotation\ApiResource;
use App\Controller\ContactsFromTagController;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Annotation\Groups;
use ApiPlatform\Core\Annotation\ApiFilter;
use ApiPlatform\Core\Bridge\Doctrine\Orm\Filter\NumericFilter;
use ApiPlatform\Core\Bridge\Doctrine\Orm\Filter\SearchFilter;
/**
 * Contacts
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="contacts", indexes={@ORM\Index(name="contactIdPersonne", columns={"idPersonne"}), @ORM\Index(name="contactIdAdresse", columns={"idAdresse"}), @ORM\Index(name="contactIdOrganisation", columns={"idOrganisation"})})
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\ContactsRepository")
 * 
 * @ApiResource(
 *      normalizationContext={
 *          "groups"={"contacts:read"}
 *      },
 *      collectionOperations={
 *          "get",
 *          "post",
 *          "get_manager_datas"={
 *              "method" = "GET",
 *              "path" = "/list_manager_datas",
 *              "controller" = ContactsFromTagController::class
 *           }
 *      }
 * )
 * 
 * @ApiFilter(NumericFilter::class, properties={"actif"})
 * @ApiFilter(SearchFilter::class, properties={"idContact": "exact"})
 * @ApiFilter(SearchFilter::class, properties={"personne.nom": "start"})
 * @ApiFilter(SearchFilter::class, properties={"personne.prenom": "start"})
 */
class Contacts
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="idContact", type="smallint", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     * @Groups({"contacts:read", "actionclients:in"})
     */
    private $idContact;

    /**
     * @var string|null
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="libelle", type="string", length=100, nullable=true)
     * @Groups({"contacts:read"})
     */
    private $libelle;

    /**
     * @var string|null
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="fonction", type="string", length=100, nullable=true)
     * @Groups("contacts:read")
     */
    private $fonction;

    /**
     * @var string|null
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="departement", type="string", length=100, nullable=true)
     * @Groups("contacts:read")
     */
    private $departement;

    /**
     * @var string|null
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="login", type="string", length=6, nullable=true)
     * @Groups("contacts:read")
     */
    private $login;

    /**
     * @var string|null
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="numeroPointage", type="string", length=6, nullable=true)
     * @Groups("contacts:read")
     */
    private $numeroPointage;

    /**
     * @var int|null
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="actif", type="smallint", nullable=true)
     * @Groups("contacts:read")
     */
    private $actif;

    /**
     * @var int|null
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="demandeSuppression", type="smallint", nullable=true)
     * @Groups("contacts:read")
     */
    private $demandeSuppression;

    /**
     * @var string|null
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="statut", type="string", length=10, nullable=true)
     * @Groups("contacts:read")
     */
    private $statut;

    /**
     * @var \Adresses
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Adresses")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="idAdresse", referencedColumnName="idAdresse")
     * })
     * @Groups("contacts:read")
     */
    private $adresse;

    /**
     * @var \Organisations
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Organisations")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="idOrganisation", referencedColumnName="idOrganisation")
     * })
     * @ApiFilter(NumericFilter::class, properties={"organisation.idOrganisation"})
     * @Groups({"contacts:read", "actionclients:in"})
     */
    private $organisation;

    /**
     * @var \Personnes
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Personnes")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="idPersonne", referencedColumnName="idPersonne")
     * })
     * @Groups({"contacts:read", "actionclients:in"})
     */
    private $personne;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity=Tagsattribues::class, mappedBy="contact")
     * @Groups("contacts:read")
     */
    private $tagsAttribues;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity=Coordonnees::class, mappedBy="contact")
     * @Groups("contacts:read")
     */
    private $coordonnees;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->tagsAttribues = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->coordonnees = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getIdContact(): ?int
    {
        return $this->idContact;
    }

    public function getLibelle(): ?string
    {
        return $this->libelle;
    }

    public function setLibelle(?string $libelle): self
    {
        $this->libelle = $libelle;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getFonction(): ?string
    {
        return $this->fonction;
    }

    public function setFonction(?string $fonction): self
    {
        $this->fonction = $fonction;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getDepartement(): ?string
    {
        return $this->departement;
    }

    public function setDepartement(?string $departement): self
    {
        $this->departement = $departement;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getLogin(): ?string
    {
        return $this->login;
    }

    public function setLogin(?string $login): self
    {
        $this->login = $login;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getNumeroPointage(): ?string
    {
        return $this->numeroPointage;
    }

    public function setNumeroPointage(?string $numeroPointage): self
    {
        $this->numeroPointage = $numeroPointage;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getActif(): ?int
    {
        return $this->actif;
    }

    public function setActif(?int $actif): self
    {
        $this->actif = $actif;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getDemandeSuppression(): ?int
    {
        return $this->demandeSuppression;
    }

    public function setDemandeSuppression(?int $demandeSuppression): self
    {
        $this->demandeSuppression = $demandeSuppression;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getStatut(): ?string
    {
        return $this->statut;
    }

    public function setStatut(?string $statut): self
    {
        $this->statut = $statut;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getAdresse(): ?Adresses
    {
        return $this->adresse;
    }

    public function setAdresse(?Adresses $adresse): self
    {
        $this->adresse = $adresse;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getOrganisation(): ?Organisations
    {
        return $this->organisation;
    }

    public function setOrganisation(?Organisations $organisation): self
    {
        $this->organisation = $organisation;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getPersonne(): ?Personnes
    {
        return $this->personne;
    }

    public function setPersonne(?Personnes $personne): self
    {
        $this->personne = $personne;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection|Tagsattribues[]
     */
    public function getTagsAttribues(): Collection
    {
        return $this->tagsAttribues;
    }

    public function addTagsAttribue(Tagsattribues $tagsAttribue): self
    {
        if (!$this->tagsAttribues->contains($tagsAttribue)) {
            $this->tagsAttribues[] = $tagsAttribue;
            $tagsAttribue->setContacts($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeTagsAttribue(Tagsattribues $tagsAttribue): self
    {
        if ($this->tagsAttribues->removeElement($tagsAttribue)) {
            // set the owning side to null (unless already changed)
            if ($tagsAttribue->getContacts() === $this) {
                $tagsAttribue->setContacts(null);
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection|Coordonnees[]
     */
    public function getCoordonnees(): Collection
    {
        return $this->coordonnees;
    }

    public function addCoordonnee(Coordonnees $coordonnee): self
    {
        if (!$this->coordonnees->contains($coordonnee)) {
            $this->coordonnees[] = $coordonnee;
            $coordonnee->setContact($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeCoordonnee(Coordonnees $coordonnee): self
    {
        if ($this->coordonnees->removeElement($coordonnee)) {
            // set the owning side to null (unless already changed)
            if ($coordonnee->getContact() === $this) {
                $coordonnee->setContact(null);
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }


}
```

```
[
  {
    "idContact": 0,
    "libelle": "string",
    "fonction": "string",
    "departement": "string",
    "login": "string",
    "numeroPointage": "string",
    "actif": 0,
    "demandeSuppression": 0,
    "statut": "string",
    "adresse": {
      "idAdresse": 0,
      "libelle": "string",
      "batimentfr": "string",
      "batimentnl": "string",
      "ruefr": "string",
      "ruenl": "string"
    },
    "organisation": {
      "idOrganisation": 0,
      "denominationfr": "string",
      "denominationnl": "string",
      "abreviationfr": "string",
      "abreviationnl": "string",
      "organisme": "string",
      "libelleorganisme": "string",
      "dossierkp": "string",
      "iduserkb": 0,
      "isclient": true,
      "idclientnavision": "string",
      "isfournisseur": true,
      "idfournisseurnavision": "string",
      "numeroentreprise": "string",
      "bilingue": 0,
      "fictif": 0,
      "actif": 0
    },
    "personne": {
      "idPersonne": 0,
      "genre": "string",
      "particule": "string",
      "nom": "string",
      "prenom": "string",
      "roleLinguistique": "string",
      "homonyme": "string",
      "actif": true,
      "statut": "string"
    },
    "tagsAttribues": [
      {
        "idTagAttribue": 0,
        "tag": {
          "idTag": 0,
          "libellefr": "string",
          "libellenl": "string",
          "actif": true,
          "hereditaire": true,
          "public": true,
          "tagsDivisions": [
            "string"
          ]
        }
      }
    ],
    "coordonnees": [
      {
        "idCoordonnee": 0,
        "contenu": "string",
        "pays": {
          "idPays": 0,
          "code": "string",
          "libellefr": "string",
          "libellenl": "string",
          "libelleen": "string",
          "prefixe": "string"
        },
        "typeCoordonnee": {
          "idTypeCoordonnee": 0,
          "nature": "string",
          "libellefr": "string",
          "libellenl": "string",
          "glyphicon": "string"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

*From debugger of Symfony server*

```
[PHP-FPM    ] [25-Nov-2022 15:37:05 Europe/Berlin] [info] Matched route "api_contacts_get_collection".
[PHP-FPM    ] [25-Nov-2022 15:37:05 Europe/Berlin] [debug] Checking for authenticator support.
[PHP-FPM    ] [25-Nov-2022 15:37:05 Europe/Berlin] [debug] Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\DebugHandlersListener::configure".
[PHP-FPM    ] [25-Nov-2022 15:37:05 Europe/Berlin] [debug] Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\ValidateRequestListener::onKernelRequest".
[PHP-FPM    ] [25-Nov-2022 15:37:05 Europe/Berlin] [debug] Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Nelmio\CorsBundle\EventListener\CorsListener::onKernelRequest".
[PHP-FPM    ] [25-Nov-2022 15:37:05 Europe/Berlin] [debug] Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\SessionListener::onKernelRequest".
[PHP-FPM    ] [25-Nov-2022 15:37:05 Europe/Berlin] [debug] Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\LocaleListener::setDefaultLocale".
[PHP-FPM    ] [25-Nov-2022 15:37:05 Europe/Berlin] [debug] Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\RouterListener::onKernelRequest".
[PHP-FPM    ] [25-Nov-2022 15:37:05 Europe/Berlin] [debug] Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "ApiPlatform\Core\EventListener\QueryParameterValidateListener::onKernelRequest".
[PHP-FPM    ] [25-Nov-2022 15:37:05 Europe/Berlin] [debug] Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\LocaleListener::onKernelRequest".
[PHP-FPM    ] [25-Nov-2022 15:37:05 Europe/Berlin] [debug] Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\LocaleAwareListener::onKernelRequest".
[PHP-FPM    ] [25-Nov-2022 15:37:05 Europe/Berlin] [debug] Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Bundle\SecurityBundle\Debug\TraceableFirewallListener::configureLogoutUrlGenerator".
[PHP-FPM    ] [25-Nov-2022 15:37:05 Europe/Berlin] [debug] Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Bundle\SecurityBundle\Debug\TraceableFirewallListener::onKernelRequest".
[PHP-FPM    ] [25-Nov-2022 15:37:05 Europe/Berlin] [debug] Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "ApiPlatform\Core\EventListener\AddFormatListener::onKernelRequest".
[PHP-FPM    ] [25-Nov-2022 15:37:05 Europe/Berlin] [debug] Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "ApiPlatform\Core\EventListener\ReadListener::onKernelRequest".
[PHP-FPM    ] [25-Nov-2022 15:37:05 Europe/Berlin] [debug] Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "ApiPlatform\Core\Security\EventListener\DenyAccessListener::onSecurity".
[PHP-FPM    ] [25-Nov-2022 15:37:05 Europe/Berlin] [debug] Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "ApiPlatform\Core\EventListener\DeserializeListener::onKernelRequest".
[PHP-FPM    ] [25-Nov-2022 15:37:05 Europe/Berlin] [debug] Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "ApiPlatform\Core\Security\EventListener\DenyAccessListener::onSecurityPostDenormalize".
[PHP-FPM    ] [25-Nov-2022 15:37:05 Europe/Berlin] [debug] Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "ApiPlatform\Core\Bridge\Symfony\Bundle\EventListener\SwaggerUiListener::onKernelRequest".
[PHP-FPM    ] [25-Nov-2022 15:37:05 Europe/Berlin] [debug] Notified event "kernel.controller_arguments" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\ErrorListener::onControllerArguments".
[PHP-FPM    ] [25-Nov-2022 15:37:05 Europe/Berlin] [debug] SELECT DISTINCT c0_.idContact AS idContact_0, c0_.idContact AS idContact_1 FROM contacts c0_ LEFT JOIN adresses a1_ ON c0_.idAdresse = a1_.idAdresse LEFT JOIN organisations o2_ ON c0_.idOrganisation = o2_.idOrganisation LEFT JOIN personnes p3_ ON c0_.idPersonne = p3_.idPersonne LEFT JOIN tagsattribues t4_ ON c0_.idContact = t4_.idContact LEFT JOIN tags t5_ ON t4_.idTag = t5_.idTag LEFT JOIN coordonnees c6_ ON c0_.idContact = c6_.idContact LEFT JOIN pays p7_ ON c6_.idPays = p7_.idPays LEFT JOIN typescoordonnees t8_ ON c6_.idTypeCoordonnee = t8_.idTypeCoordonnee ORDER BY c0_.idContact ASC LIMIT 1
[PHP-FPM    ] [25-Nov-2022 15:37:16 Europe/Berlin] [debug] SELECT c0_.idContact AS idContact_0, c0_.libelle AS libelle_1, c0_.fonction AS fonction_2, c0_.departement AS departement_3, c0_.login AS login_4, c0_.numeroPointage AS numeroPointage_5, c0_.actif AS actif_6, c0_.demandeSuppression AS demandeSuppression_7, c0_.statut AS statut_8, a1_.idAdresse AS idAdresse_9, a1_.libelle AS libelle_10, a1_.batimentFr AS batimentFr_11, a1_.batimentNl AS batimentNl_12, a1_.rueFr AS rueFr_13, a1_.rueNl AS rueNl_14, a1_.numero AS numero_15, a1_.boite AS boite_16, a1_.statut AS statut_17, o2_.idOrganisation AS idOrganisation_18, o2_.denominationFr AS denominationFr_19, o2_.denominationNl AS denominationNl_20, o2_.abreviationFr AS abreviationFr_21, o2_.abreviationNl AS abreviationNl_22, o2_.organisme AS organisme_23, o2_.libelleOrganisme AS libelleOrganisme_24, o2_.dossierKP AS dossierKP_25, o2_.idUserKb AS idUserKb_26, o2_.isClient AS isClient_27, o2_.idClientNavision AS idClientNavision_28, o2_.isFournisseur AS isFournisseur_29, o2_.idFournisseurNavision AS idFournisseurNavision_30, o2_.numeroEntreprise AS numeroEntreprise_31, o2_.bilingue AS bilingue_32, o2_.fictif AS fictif_33, o2_.actif AS actif_34, p3_.idPersonne AS idPersonne_35, p3_.genre AS genre_36, p3_.particule AS particule_37, p3_.nom AS nom_38, p3_.prenom AS prenom_39, p3_.roleLinguistique AS roleLinguistique_40, p3_.homonyme AS homonyme_41, p3_.actif AS actif_42, p3_.statut AS statut_43, t4_.idTagAttribue AS idTagAttribue_44, t5_.idTag AS idTag_45, t5_.libelleFr AS libelleFr_46, t5_.libelleNl AS libelleNl_47, t5_.actif AS actif_48, t5_.hereditaire AS hereditaire_49, t5_.public AS public_50, c6_.idCoordonnee AS idCoordonnee_51, c6_.contenu AS contenu_52, p7_.idPays AS idPays_53, p7_.code AS code_54, p7_.libelleFr AS libelleFr_55, p7_.libelleNl AS libelleNl_56, p7_.libelleEn AS libelleEn_57, p7_.prefixe AS prefixe_58, t8_.idTypeCoordonnee AS idTypeCoordonnee_59, t8_.souche AS souche_60, t8_.nature AS nature_61, t8_.libelleFr AS libelleFr_62, t8_.libelleNl AS libelleNl_63, t8_.glyphicon AS glyphicon_64, c0_.idAdresse AS idAdresse_65, c0_.idOrganisation AS idOrganisation_66, c0_.idPersonne AS idPersonne_67, a1_.idLocalite AS idLocalite_68, a1_.idOrganisation AS idOrganisation_69, t4_.idOrganisation AS idOrganisation_70, t4_.idTag AS idTag_71, t4_.idContact AS idContact_72, c6_.idContact AS idContact_73, c6_.idOrganisation AS idOrganisation_74, c6_.idPays AS idPays_75, c6_.idTypeCoordonnee AS idTypeCoordonnee_76 FROM contacts c0_ LEFT JOIN adresses a1_ ON c0_.idAdresse = a1_.idAdresse LEFT JOIN organisations o2_ ON c0_.idOrganisation = o2_.idOrganisation LEFT JOIN personnes p3_ ON c0_.idPersonne = p3_.idPersonne LEFT JOIN tagsattribues t4_ ON c0_.idContact = t4_.idContact LEFT JOIN tags t5_ ON t4_.idTag = t5_.idTag LEFT JOIN coordonnees c6_ ON c0_.idContact = c6_.idContact LEFT JOIN pays p7_ ON c6_.idPays = p7_.idPays LEFT JOIN typescoordonnees t8_ ON c6_.idTypeCoordonnee = t8_.idTypeCoordonnee WHERE c0_.idContact IN (?) ORDER BY c0_.idContact ASC
[Web Server ] Nov 25 15:37:16 |INFO   | SERVER GET  (200) /api/contacts?page=1&itemsPerPage=1 ip="::1"
[PHP-FPM    ] [25-Nov-2022 15:37:16 Europe/Berlin] [debug] SELECT t0.idTagDivision AS idTagDivision_1, t0.idOrganisation AS idOrganisation_2, t0.idTag AS idTag_3 FROM tagsdivisions t0 WHERE t0.idTag = ?
[PHP-FPM    ] [25-Nov-2022 15:37:16 Europe/Berlin] [debug] SELECT t0.idTagDivision AS idTagDivision_1, t0.idOrganisation AS idOrganisation_2, t0.idTag AS idTag_3 FROM tagsdivisions t0 WHERE t0.idTag = ?
[PHP-FPM    ] [25-Nov-2022 15:37:16 Europe/Berlin] [debug] Notified event "kernel.view" to listener "ApiPlatform\Core\Validator\EventListener\ValidateListener::onKernelView".
[PHP-FPM    ] [25-Nov-2022 15:37:16 Europe/Berlin] [debug] Notified event "kernel.view" to listener "App\EventSubscriber\LogSubscriber::onKernelRequest".
[PHP-FPM    ] [25-Nov-2022 15:37:16 Europe/Berlin] [debug] Notified event "kernel.view" to listener "ApiPlatform\Core\EventListener\WriteListener::onKernelView".
[PHP-FPM    ] [25-Nov-2022 15:37:16 Europe/Berlin] [debug] Notified event "kernel.view" to listener "ApiPlatform\Core\EventListener\SerializeListener::onKernelView".
[PHP-FPM    ] [25-Nov-2022 15:37:16 Europe/Berlin] [debug] Notified event "kernel.view" to listener "ApiPlatform\Core\EventListener\RespondListener::onKernelView".
[PHP-FPM    ] [25-Nov-2022 15:37:16 Europe/Berlin] [debug] Listener "ApiPlatform\Core\EventListener\RespondListener::onKernelView" stopped propagation of the event "kernel.view".
[PHP-FPM    ] [25-Nov-2022 15:37:16 Europe/Berlin] [debug] Notified event "kernel.response" to listener "Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Firewall\ContextListener::onKernelResponse".
[PHP-FPM    ] [25-Nov-2022 15:37:16 Europe/Berlin] [debug] Notified event "kernel.response" to listener "Nelmio\CorsBundle\EventListener\CorsListener::onKernelResponse".
[PHP-FPM    ] [25-Nov-2022 15:37:16 Europe/Berlin] [debug] Notified event "kernel.response" to listener "Nelmio\CorsBundle\EventListener\CacheableResponseVaryListener::onResponse".
[PHP-FPM    ] [25-Nov-2022 15:37:16 Europe/Berlin] [debug] Notified event "kernel.response" to listener "ApiPlatform\Core\Hydra\EventListener\AddLinkHeaderListener::onKernelResponse".
[PHP-FPM    ] [25-Nov-2022 15:37:16 Europe/Berlin] [debug] Notified event "kernel.response" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\ResponseListener::onKernelResponse".
[PHP-FPM    ] [25-Nov-2022 15:37:16 Europe/Berlin] [debug] Notified event "kernel.response" to listener "Symfony\Component\WebLink\EventListener\AddLinkHeaderListener::onKernelResponse".
[PHP-FPM    ] [25-Nov-2022 15:37:16 Europe/Berlin] [debug] Notified event "kernel.response" to listener "Symfony\Component\Security\Http\RememberMe\ResponseListener::onKernelResponse".
[PHP-FPM    ] [25-Nov-2022 15:37:16 Europe/Berlin] [debug] Notified event "kernel.response" to listener "ApiPlatform\Core\HttpCache\EventListener\AddHeadersListener::onKernelResponse".
[PHP-FPM    ] [25-Nov-2022 15:37:16 Europe/Berlin] [debug] Notified event "kernel.response" to listener "ApiPlatform\Core\HttpCache\EventListener\AddTagsListener::onKernelResponse".
[PHP-FPM    ] [25-Nov-2022 15:37:16 Europe/Berlin] [debug] Notified event "kernel.response" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\ErrorListener::removeCspHeader".
[PHP-FPM    ] [25-Nov-2022 15:37:16 Europe/Berlin] [debug] Notified event "kernel.response" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\DisallowRobotsIndexingListener::onResponse".
[PHP-FPM    ] [25-Nov-2022 15:37:16 Europe/Berlin] [debug] Notified event "kernel.response" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\SessionListener::onKernelResponse".
[PHP-FPM    ] [25-Nov-2022 15:37:16 Europe/Berlin] [debug] Notified event "kernel.response" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\StreamedResponseListener::onKernelResponse".
[PHP-FPM    ] [25-Nov-2022 15:37:16 Europe/Berlin] [debug] Notified event "kernel.finish_request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\LocaleListener::onKernelFinishRequest".
[PHP-FPM    ] [25-Nov-2022 15:37:16 Europe/Berlin] [debug] Notified event "kernel.finish_request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\SessionListener::onFinishRequest".
[PHP-FPM    ] [25-Nov-2022 15:37:16 Europe/Berlin] [debug] Notified event "kernel.finish_request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\RouterListener::onKernelFinishRequest".
[PHP-FPM    ] [25-Nov-2022 15:37:16 Europe/Berlin] [debug] Notified event "kernel.finish_request" to listener "Symfony\Bundle\SecurityBundle\Debug\TraceableFirewallListener::onKernelFinishRequest".
[PHP-FPM    ] [25-Nov-2022 15:37:16 Europe/Berlin] [debug] Notified event "kernel.finish_request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\LocaleAwareListener::onKernelFinishRequest".
```

Request : http://localhost:8000/api/contacts?page=1&itemsPerPage=30

Do you have any idea about the performances issues?

Comment: You need to log your queries. For example if you list articles with their tags but you dont use a join on the query, for each item, symfony will query "select tags where article_id =?" so you have 30 queries just to add tags on your articles.

Comment: @CharlieLucas After learning about EAGER and LAZY loading, I've conclude, the issue is there a select "DISTINCT" with a JOIN on my OneToMany...

Is there a solution to exclude a property from distinct without manual writing?